# How to make elements stop from moving when the screen is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, less

I have a container with a background image with markers/"elements" on the background image. When I resize the screen I need the markers to be in same place. I am trying to make it responsive but when I resize the window, the elements don't seem to sit in their position.

I know this is because the background image moves and I need all the elements with the image to be locked in the same spot.

http://codepen.io/Sonick/pen/huqrl

```
.container {
    background: url("http://armsonick.zz.mu/Demos/ImageHost/images/1381607643scene1.png") no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
    color: #000000;
    height: 535px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 1030px;
}

.dialog {
    background-color: rgba(163, 154, 77, 0.9);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: none;
    height: 140px;
    left: 343px;
    line-height: 24px;
    padding: 100px 30px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 97px;
    width: 280px;
    z-index: 10;

    -moz-border-radius: 170px;
    -ms-border-radius: 170px;
    -o-border-radius: 170px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 170px;
    border-radius: 170px;
}
.dialog .close {
    color: black;
    background-color: #65683b;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 36px;
    line-height: 36px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 60px;
    width: 36px;

    -moz-border-radius: 18px;
    -ms-border-radius: 18px;
    -o-border-radius: 18px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 18px;
    border-radius: 18px;
}
.labels p {
    display: none;
}
.labels div {
    background-color: rgba(203, 189, 58, 0.8);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: none;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 30px 0 0;
    position: absolute !important;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 80px;

    -moz-border-radius: 40px;
    -ms-border-radius: 40px;
    -o-border-radius: 40px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
    border-radius: 40px;
}
.labels > div {
    background-color: rgba(203, 189, 58, 0.8);

    -moz-transition: .3s;
    -ms-transition: .3s;
    -o-transition: .3s;
    -webkit-transition: .3s;
    transition: .3s;
}
.labels div:hover {
    background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.8);
}
.labels div span {
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 15px solid rgba(203, 189, 58, 0.8);
    bottom: -14px;
    height: 0;
    left: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;

    -moz-transition: .3s;
    -ms-transition: .3s;
    -o-transition: .3s;
    -webkit-transition: .3s;
    transition: .3s;
}
.labels div:hover span {
    border-top: 15px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.8);
}
#label1 {
    left: 720px;
    top: 215px;
}
#label2 {
    left: 495px;
    top: 290px;
}
#label3 {
    left: 450px;
    top: 115px;
}
#label4 {
    left: 270px;
    top: 170px;
}
#label5 {
    left: 570px;
    top: 65px;
}
#label6 {
    left: 275px;
    top: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Use percentages instead of px values for positioning your markers. Nice illustration btw.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the background of the `body` - which the `div` elements are designed to line up with - is aligned centrally, whereas the `absolute` positioning of those divs can only work from the top/left of the containing div. This means that when the container is smaller than the background image the alignment will be off.

Instead you need to align the background image to the same anchor point as the `div` elements for this to work; the `top`/`left`:

```
body {
    background: url(http://pcvector.net/uploads/demo/scripts/layout_and_interface/isometric_interactive/images/scene.jpg) left top no-repeat;
}
```

[**Updated example**](http://jsfiddle.net/nztobs7x/)

Comment: That works, but is there a way to do it within container div?

Comment: Yes, it would work if you put the background on the `.container` element too: http://jsfiddle.net/nztobs7x/1/. Note that the URL to the original image on the container element went to a 404 so I simply replaced it. You should also check your HTML as you have several `</span>` elements with no matching opening tag.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you set the `.container` element with a fixed width (1030px). So what happens is, on a screen smaller than 1030px the elements doesn't respond to the viewport.

Change your `.container` to `max-width:1030px;` rather than `width:1030px`

http://jsfiddle.net/ggChris/jjk52j7q/

Comment: That still doesn't work, when you move the screen the markers move

Answer (score 0):

To create a responsive design, you have to use `%` in the css properties instead of `px`

I mean, you have this:

```
#label1 {
    left: 720px;
    top: 215px;
}
```

But it should be:

```
#label1 {
    left: 69%;
    top: 40%;
}
```

Hope it helps.